# F# Calculate function that based on previous value of Sequence

Tags: f#

I want to get new seq that contains value calculated (x<sub>i</sub>-x<sub>i-1</sub>)/x<sub>i-1</sub>. How to do that without for statement?

```
let GAZP = seq  [ 183.24; 170.15;174.17;170.67;170.15;171.2;172.56;178.1;191.5;190.5;175.1]

let gazpReturnRate =
    GAZP
    |> Seq.skip 1
    |> Seq.map(fun x -> x)

printf "%A" gazpReturnRate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Seq.pairwise`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.pairwise%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D). It creates a sequence of all consequitive pairs:

```
GAZP
|> Seq.pairwise
|> Seq.map (fun (xn_1, xn) -> (xn - xn_1) / xn_1)
```